# Кастомные атрибуты в Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Можно ли задать свои атрибуты для полей формы, используя плагин [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/) и **без js** ?

К примеру есть такое поле (и не одно на странице, отличаются `id`, `data-msg`) на странице:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="name" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="name-1"
       data-attr="custom" 
       data-msg="Текст 1">
```

**Вопрос:** есть ли возможность задавать эти кастомные атрибуты полей в админке (там же где задаются поля формы)?

Что-то типа такого:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_class_attr', 'custom_custom_form_class_attr' );
function custom_custom_form_class_attr ...
```